# How to open file from installation directory?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Passing the PATH to custom action

```
<Property Id="ModifyConfig" Value="PATH=[PATH]"/>
<CustomAction Id='ModifyConfig'
          BinaryKey="WebAppCA"
          DllEntry="ModifyConfig"
          Execute="deferred"
          Return="check"
          HideTarget="no"
          Impersonate="no"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ModifyConfig" After="InstallFiles"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My custom action

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult ModifyConfig(Session session)
    {
            string PATH = session.CustomActionData["PATH"];

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(PATH + "appsettings.json");
            session.Log("PATH: " + PATH);
            session.Log("Search for configuration file " + file.FullName);
     }
```

When custom action executes I get following in log:

```
    PATH: C:\MyPath\
    Search for configuration file C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIE38D.tmp-\C:\MyPath\appsettings.json
```

How it can be and how I can get the file?

EDIT: This works good - Execute="**immediate**" and After="**InstallFinalize**"

```
<CustomAction Id='ModifyConfig'
          BinaryKey="WebAppCA"
          DllEntry="ModifConfig"
          Execute="immediate"
          Return="check"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ModifyConfig" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: What are you doing with `PATH=[PATH]`? Where do you intend to install the file in question? Somewhere in the system path? You need to use custom actions to assign values to properties like that. You should also not reference "PATH" since that clashes with the built-in system environment Path variable.

Comment: [Lurking on github.com can help to see how others do things](https://github.com/egandro/wixmvc6/blob/1e3c51d04ff77d5d299cb2148b93c2657cf66285/IISManager/CustomAction.cs) (bottom). [More search hits](https://github.com/search?q=%5BCustomAction%5D+appsettings.json&type=Code).

Comment: The first link was very helpful. But I still don't understand why this is not working in deferred action. Anyway, the problem is solved.

Comment: What were you doing in the immediate mode set property custom action? Maybe you were setting an unexpected path there that showed up in deferred mode?